# Passing a handler function as a prop. How do I have the parent understand which child was clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom-events, state

So I have a parent functional component that looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import './resources/projects.css';
import ProjectsObject from './resources/projectDetailsObject';
import ProjectCard from './ProjectCard';

const Projects = () => {
    const projectsArray = Object.keys(ProjectsObject);

    const initialState = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < projectsArray.length; i++) {
        initialState[projectsArray[i]] = false;
    }

    console.log(initialState);

    const [toggleObject, setToggleObject] = useState(initialState);

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        // setToggleArray(() => {
        //     const newToggles = [];
        //     for (let i = 0; i < toggleArray.length; i++) {
        //         if (i === index) newToggles.push(true);
        //         else newToggles.push(false);
        //     }
        //     console.log(newToggles);
        //     return newToggles;
        // });
        console.log(`clicked item at index: ${}.`)
    }
    return (
            <section className="projects">
                {projectsArray.map((project, index) => (
                    <ProjectCard 
                        toggled={toggleObject[project]} 
                        key={index} 
                        project={ProjectsObject[project]}
                        handleClick={handleClick}
                        index={index}
                    />)
                )}
            </section>
    )
}

export default Projects;
```

I'm trying to pass a click handler down to the child div/article elements

Here's what the child component looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import Projects from './resources/projectDetailsObject'

const ProjectCard = ({ project, toggled, handleClick, index }) => {
    console.log(project);
    console.log(toggled);
    console.log(index);

    let displayedContent = !toggled ? (
        <article className="single-project" data-id={index} onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>
            <div className="snakeLists project-title">{Projects[project.id].title}</div>
            <div className="clone"></div>
        </article>
    ) : (
        <article className="single-project" data-id={index} onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>
            <div className="description">
                <h2>{Projects[project.id].title}</h2>
                <p>{Projects[project.id].description.text}</p>
                <br></br><a href={Projects[project.id].description.link}><h2>check it out.</h2></a>
            </div>

            <div className="snippet">
                <img src={Projects[project.id].img.src} alt={Projects[project.id].img.alt}/>
            </div>
        </article>
    );

    return (
        <>
            {displayedContent}
        </>
    );
}

export default ProjectCard;
```

Currently I can't figure out how to grab any values from the clicked child. I tried giving `data-id={index}` to the `<article>` element in the child component return.

Then I tried to console.log the `e.target.dataset.id` as well as `e.currentTarget.dataset.id` . Both of these turned up undefined.

How do I reference which child was clicked? I need this to set the state of the parent.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you pass `index` to `handleClick`? `<article onClick={e => handleClick(e, index)}/>`. You'll get index in parent: `function handleClick(e, index) { console.log(index) }`

Comment: I certainly hope so. I thought about that a while ago but I don't think I actually tried it. Give me a sec

Comment: @Eggy I just tried it and it said it was undefined

Comment: @Eggy ok in the interpolated string I was using it said undefined, but I switched to just console.log(index), and its giving me the right number...

Comment: @Eggy I switched my state back to an array and was able to grab the index the way you said to do. If you want to type your first comment into a short answer I'll flag it. THANKS!